# Error al dar de alta objeto con lista de objetos con referencia a otros objetos obtenidos de otro contexto ENTITY FRAMEWORK C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Esoty teniendo un problema.

Este es mi dominio :

**Clase1**
*List  clases2;*

**Clase2**
*Clase3 clase3;
Clase4 clase4;*

Para crear la clase 2 , consulto a un contexto que me devuelve la Clase3 y Clase4 (ya existen ambas 2)

Luego de crearlo (la clase2) , lo doy de alta a la lista de Clase1.

Cuando voy a dar de alta la Clase2 en la base de datos,uso otro contexto, me guarda nuevamente la clase3 y clase4.

Lo que entiendo es que al cambiar de contexto EF piensa que es un objeto nuevo.
Entonces, probe hacer un foreach de la lista de clase2  que contiene la clase1 poniendole a cada clase2  EntityState.Unchanged pero me tira este error :

> Attaching an entity of type 'clase3' failed because another entity of
>   the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen
>   when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Puedes poner el código?